# How to compile or use a library that downloaded online

Tags: c++, dll, static-libraries, rtaudio

I am unfamiliar with C++ but I got a project that needed to deal with it.

I need to use a library available online, RtAudio, and of course I need to 
import it in my program.

My question is, how do I use/do it?

Here is my understanding on the library, I am sure that I am totally wrong, but 
just to tell where I am.

I think i cannot use the file that I download directly but change it to a lib file and a dll file (as I have use some other precompile library before and it only require a dll and lib file[.h too of course]; I know how to put these into MSVC 2015 and use it).

And also I think in order to compile the library into dll and lib file I need to do something with the follow file in the cmd in window: configure, install, and makefile.in

I am desperate as I had already given up using another library before as I do not know how to deal with this, therefore it will be nice that if anyone can give any help. Thanks.

Comment: Looking at `github` it looks like you compile it with `CMake`.

Comment: Every decent library comes with installation instructions. Have you read ones for yours?

Comment: Instructions how to build it with `CMake` are here: https://github.com/thestk/rtaudio/blob/master/install.txt

Comment: BTW (since the 5 min edit window has passed on my first comment), What I mean about compiling with `CMake` is that you use `CMake` to generate Visual Studio 2015 project files. Then build using VS as normal.

Comment: Thanks for the reply first of all. 
The problem is I do not even know what you say by "use CMake to generate Visual Studio 2015 project files" I know CMake but what is general a project file, and how to I do with it. 
In any other way I understand lib and dll is because I just need to use it.
I have also tried to use g++ with mingw to run the configure file but it just say cannot recognize mingw or g++, but I already did install and but MinGw/bin in the path file